# How to add a project item to the repository with empty and not empty folders in Delphi 10.3.3

Tags: delphi, directory, repository

I've created a project skeleton and added to the repository as a custom item. But when I want to create a project by the repository, it says:

`Could not copy file basefoldername\subfoldername1\filename1.pas`

I examined the radstudiorepository.xml and found a section like this

```
<RADStudioObjectRepository Version="">
  ...
  <Items>
    ...
    <Item IDString="my repository item project name">
      ...
      <Files>
        <File>basefoldername\subfoldername1\filename1.pas</File>
        <File>basefoldername\subfoldername2\filename2.pas</File>
        ...
      </Files>
    </Item>
    ...
  </Items>
  ...
</RADStudioObjectRepository>
```

I haven't found a DTD or XSD for RADStudioObjectRepository on the net.
Could you tell me how could I register a folder to create in this xml file?

You can find the `radstudiorepository.xml` in this way:

- Select menu item **File\New\Other**
- On the right pane of the **New Items** dialog **RIGHT** click on any item
- Select the **Template libraries** popup menu item
- In the **Template libraries** dialog you can see the value assigned to **RAD Studio Object Repository**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Folders` tag must be before the `Files` one. The `Folders` tag contains `Folder` tags just like `Files` contains `File` ones. The `Folder` tag text content should be the folder name, just like the `File` tag text content the file name.

```
<RADStudioObjectRepository Version="">
  ...
  <Items>
    ...
    <Item IDString="my repository item project name">
      ...
      <Folders>
        <Folder>basefoldername\subfoldername1\</Folder>
        <Folder>basefoldername\subfoldername2\</Folder>
        ...
      </Folders>
      <Files>
        <File>basefoldername\subfoldername1\filename1.pas</File>
        <File>basefoldername\subfoldername2\filename2.pas</File>
        ...
      </Files>
    </Item>
    ...
  </Items>
  ...
</RADStudioObjectRepository>
```